# Change of variables in Riemann–Stieltjes integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I want
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(g(x))dg=\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt,\tag{$\heartsuit$}\label{heart}
\end{equation}
where $g$ is a continuous but not necessarily monotone (or bounded variation) function of $[a,b]$, both integrals are Riemann–Stieltjes (that is, $\int_a^b h(x)dg(x)$ is the limit of Riemann–Stieltjes sums $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} h(c_i)(g(x_{i+1})-g(x_i))$ where $a=x_0<x_1<\dotsb<x_n=b$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, $c_i\in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$ for $i=0,\dotsc,n-1$, and $\max \lvert x_{i+1}-x_i\rvert$ goes to 0).

If both integrals in \eqref{heart} exist, does it follow that they are equal?

Note that without continuity of $g$ this is not necessarily so, even if $g$ is increasing: say, if $a=0$, $b=1$, $g(x)=\chi_{[1/2,1]}$, and $f(0)=f(1)=0$, then LHS is 0 but RHS may be non-zero. For increasing continuous $g$ this is less or more obvious. But we sometimes would like to have not monotone change of variables (cf. $\int_a^b f(x^2)x\,dx=\frac12 \int_{a^2}^{b^2} f(t)dt$ with $a<0<b$).

If not, what are additional conditions under which \eqref{heart} holds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the answer is yes, they are equal, and perhaps you do not really need to assume the existence of the integral in the right-hand side, that is, $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t) dt$. This is proved in the context of Henstock–Kurzweil integrals as Theorem 6.1 in [1].

The key lemma is that if $g(a) = g(b)$, then $\int_a^b f(g(x)) dg(x) = 0$. This is applied to reduce the problem to the case when $g$ is monotone, which is rather well-known.

Reference:

[1] Michael Bensimhoun, *Change of Variable Theorems for the KH Integral*,  Real Analysis Exchange 35(1) (2009–2010): 167–194, [DOI:10.14321/realanalexch.35.1.0167](https://doi.org/10.14321/realanalexch.35.1.0167)

Comment: Thank you! Strictly speaking, Bensimhoun proves that RHS exists as a HK integral (assuming the same for left), that does not directly imply that it exists as R integral.

Comment: That is why I added "perhaps": one would have to look into the proof to see if "better" integrability of the LHS implies Riemann integrability of the RHS.

Comment: I think, there is a short argument (for this Riemann-Stieltjes question at least), indeed the existence of LHS yields the existing of RHS. I post it as a separate answer and would be happy if anybody else checks.

Comment: The answer of your question follows from the aforementioned result of Bensimhoun: If f(g) dg is Riemann Stieltjes integrable, then it is a fortiori KH-integrable, and thm 6.1 applies. So, if both sides are Riemann integrable, then the two integrals are equal. It is well known that Riemann-Stieltjes implies KH-stieltjes integrable, and you can check that easily by yourselves with the definitions. On the other hand, if one integral exists in the Riemannian sense, the second integral needs not (but it exists in the KH-sense, as proved by Bensimhoun).

Comment: In the end of the above comment, I meant "Bensimhoun result does not implies that if one integral exists in the Riemann sense, then the second exist in the same sense too, but just that if the two integral exists in this sense, then they must be equal.

Comment: Regarding your first comment ("assuming the same for left"), this is not assumed in the aforementioned result: On the contrary, it is proved there that if the left side exists in the KH sense, then so does the right side. But the converse is not true, and the paper of Bensimhoun provides also rather general conditions for the converse to hold.

Comment: Note: the Article by Bensimhoun can be read online: https://projecteuclid.org/journals/real-analysis-exchange/volume-35/issue-1/Change-of-Variable-Theorems-for-the-KH-Integral/rae/1272376230.full

Answer (score 4):

Let me try to give a short argument that if LHS integral exists and equals $I=\int_{a}^b f(g(x))dg$ than $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt$ exists and equals $I$.

Without loss of generality $g(a)\leqslant g(b)$, and it suffices for any fixed $I_1>I$ to find a partition of $[g(a),g(b)]$ such that upper Darboux sum for $\int f$ is at most $I_1$ (then do the same for lower Darboux sum and use the description of Riemann integral via Darboux sums). For this, we find a partition $a=\xi_0<\xi_1<\ldots<\xi_n=b$ of $[a,b]$ such that any corresponding Riemann–Stieltjes sum of $\int_a^b f(g)dg$ is less than $I_1$. Denote $$p_i=\begin{cases}\sup_{g(\xi_i)\leqslant t\leqslant g(\xi_{i+1})} f(t),&\text{if}\,\, g(\xi_i)\leqslant g(\xi_{i+1})\\
\inf_{g(\xi_{i+1})\leqslant t\leqslant g(\xi_{i})} f(t),&\text{if}\,\, g(\xi_{i+1})\leqslant g(\xi_{i})\end{cases}.$$
Then, since $g$ is continuous, using intermediate value theorem we see that $f(g(x))$ takes the values arbitrarily close to $p_i$ when $x\in [\xi_i,\xi_{i+1}]$, and we get $$\kappa:=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (g(\xi_{i+1})-g(\xi_{i}))p_i\leqslant I_1.$$

Now denote $c_0\leqslant c_1\leqslant c_2\leqslant \cdots\leqslant c_n$ the numbers $g(\xi_0),\ldots,g(\xi_n)$ in increasing order, let $c_A=g(a)$, $c_B=g(b)$. Consider the partition $c_A\leqslant \ldots\leqslant c_B$ of $[g(a),g(b)]$. I claim that corresponding upper Darboux sum for $\int_{c_A}^{c_B}f(t)dt$ is at most $\kappa$, that is sufficient for our goal. For proving this we denote $\delta_i=c_{i+1}-c_i$, and we represent each expression $g(\xi_{i+1})-g(\xi_i)$ as $\pm$ sum of several consecutive $\delta$'s. Look at the expression for $\kappa$ as a linear combination of $\delta$'s (omitting $\delta$'s which are equal to 0.) If $i<A$ or $i\geqslant B$, $\delta_i$ comes equally many times with $+p_{\ldots}$ and with $-p_{\ldots}$ (to see this, put a surveillance camera at the midpoint of this $\delta_i$ segment, and look how a fly walking by the route $g(\xi_0)\to g(\xi_1)\to\cdots \to g(\xi_n)$ flies behind the camera to left and to right). Analogously, if $A\leqslant i<B$, $\delta_i$ comes one more time more with with $+p_{\ldots}$ than with $-p_{\ldots}$. Finally, when $\delta_i$ comes with $+p_j$, we have $p_j\geqslant \sup_{t\in [c_i,c_{i+1}]} f(t)$, while when $\delta_i$ comes with $-p_j$, we have $p_j\leqslant \sup_{t\in [c_i,c_{i+1}]} f(t)$ (and even $p_j\leqslant \inf_{t\in [c_i,c_{i+1}]} f(t)$). This all yields $$\kappa\geqslant \sum_{i=A}^{B-1}\delta_i\cdot \sup_{t\in [c_i,c_{i+1}]}f(t)$$
which is a corresponding Darboux sum for $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(t)dt$.

Comment: I think it would be helpful to have details on the counts of the signs with which the $\delta_i$'s are taken. This could povide for more effortless reading.

Comment: @IosifPinelis thank you for commenting and for reading this! I added some explanation, is it better now?

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I am not sure if this is helpful to people like me who have problems reading informal writing in mathematics, with images created by others. Personally, I'd prefer a formal mathematical description of your counting process. Then I could possibly create my own images. Images in addition to a formal presentation are also fine for me, maybe even better than a purely formal presentation.

Comment: well, is such explanation better? "if we represent each $g(\xi_{i+1})-g(x_i)$ as a $\pm$ sum of $\delta$'s, and then sum up them all over $i=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, we should get $g(\xi_n)-g(\xi_0)=\delta_A+\ldots+\delta_{B-1}$, thus $\delta_i$ with $i\notin [A,B-1]$ comes equally many times with $+$ and $-$ and $\delta_i$ with $i\in [A,B-1]$ comes one more time more with + than with -."

Comment: Yes, this looks good to me.

Comment: Looks OK to me, too. A formal way to write the crucial calculation might be as in the comment that follows.

Comment: $$\begin{aligned}\sum_i (g(\xi_{i+1}) - g(\xi_i)) p_i &= \sum_{i,j} (c_{j+1} - c_j) (\mathbb 1_{\xi_i\leqslant c_j<\xi_{i+1}} \sup_{[\xi_i,\xi_{i+1}]}f - \mathbb 1_{\xi_{i+1}\leqslant c_j<\xi_i} \inf_{[\xi_i,\xi_{i+1}]}f) \\&\geqslant \sum_{i,j} (c_{j+1} - c_j) (\mathbb 1_{\xi_i\leqslant c_j<\xi_{i+1}} \sup_{[c_j,c_{j+1}]}f - \mathbb 1_{\xi_{i+1}\leqslant c_j<\xi_i} \sup_{[c_j,c_{j+1}]}f)\\&= \sum_i (c_{j+1} - c_j) \sup_{[c_j,c_{j+1}]}f \sum_j (\mathbb 1_{\xi_i\leqslant c_j<\xi_{i+1}}  - \mathbb 1_{\xi_{i+1}\leqslant c_j<\xi_i})\\&= \sum_i (c_{j+1} - c_j) \sup_{[c_j,c_{j+1}]}f \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Yes, but the last sum is not over all $i$

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Right, of course: should be $\sum_j (c_{j+1}-c_j) \mathbb 1_{g(a)\leqslant c_j<g(b)}$. Also, in the last two lines summation indices are wrong, $i$ should be $j$ and vice versa.

Comment: @Fedo Petrov. Nice adaptation of the argument of Bensimhoun to Riemann integrals ! of course, much simpler, but you could try to send a note to the Real Analysis Exchange.